# Convert my list to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, bigdata

I have a dataset of about 5 lac data. My requirement is to see the stability of two columns viz. `DRGCode` and `Cost`

```
DRGCode     Cost
1           111.23
2           784.32 
3           456.25
1           785.45
34          751.36
23          326.85 
13          546.23
2           894.26
```

My code sample is :

```
df <- read.table(file = "sample.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
listids<-list()
for (ids in unique(df$DRGCode)){
  subdf=subset(x=df, subset=df$DRGCode==ids)
  shapiro.test(subdf$Cost)
  listids[[ids]]<-shapiro.test(subdf$Cost)
}
```

There are 340 unique `DRGCode`. I calculated the normality of Cost for each group of `DRGCode` using Shapiro Normality Test which is because I want to see the stability of `Cost` for each `DRGCode`.My test results in lists which contain the normality of each `DRGCode` group something like this :

```
0.818090544832195
0.000000168898359861896
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
df$Cost
0.864388033236025
0.0000743765801011971
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
df$Cost
0.755373922653185
0.000000000000000516189042471185
```

I need to get this data in a dataframe so as to see the result more clearly, something like this :

```
DRGCode Cost Normality
```

There are lots of NULL values in my data as some DRGCode have more than 5000 samples.Being a complete newbie in this domain am clueless. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Could you see if this works, `output_result = do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$DRGCode),function(x)  { subdf=df[df$DRGCode==x,];output_df = data.frame(DRGCode=x,Cost=subdf$Cost,Normality_Stat = as.vector(shapiro.test(subdf$Cost)$statistic),Normality_PValue=as.vector(shapiro.test(subdf$Cost)$p.value)) } ))`

Comment: @Osssan Why `output_df =` ? (I mean why not just the `data.frame` call ?)

Comment: I usually have some debug statements such as  `cat("Begin DRGCode=",x, "of", "percent " = x/len(DRGCodeTotal))` followed by `return(output_df)`, this is helpful in debugging cases with large loops. Though in this case,since user has more than 500,000 rows, you are right, `output_df` assignment should be avoided

Comment: @Osssan I got this `sample size must be between 3 and 5000` and this `{
  DNAME <- deparse(substitute(x))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
  x <- sort(x[complete.cases(x)])
  n <- length(x)
  if (is.na(n) || n < 3L || n > 5000L) 
    stop("sample size must be between 3 and 5000")
  rng <- x[n] - x[1L]
  if (rng == 0) 
    stop("all 'x' values are identical")
  if (rng < 1e-10) 
    x <- x/rng
  res <- .Call(C_SWilk, x)
  RVAL <- list(statistic = c(W = res[1]), p.value = res[2], 
    method = "Shapiro-Wilk normality test", data.name = DNAME)
  class(RVAL) <- "htest"
  return(RVAL)
}`